# Alamofire, uploading MultipartFormData with struct in parameters

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

how can I add struct in parameters when uploading MultipartFormData:

```
let parameters = [
"parameter1": "test1",
"parameter2": "test2"]

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
        multipartFormData.append(structObject, withName: "user")

      if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
      multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "file.png",      mimeType: "image/png")
    }
    }, to: url, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if let value = response.result.value as AnyObject?{
                    let json = JSON(value)
                } else {

                }                    
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)

        }
    }
    )
```

I can extra parameters without any problem, but I can't add an object to parameters array

thank you

Comment: Where is your `struct`?

Comment: multipartFormData.append(structObject, withName: "user"), there case where I use simple struct, and other case where I use complex struct

Answer (score 1):

Add the following below the multipartFormData to loop between the parameters map and append the parameters key and value:

```
let parameters = [
"parameter1": "test1",
"parameter2": "test2"]

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(structObject, withName: "user")

      if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
      multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "file.png",      mimeType: "image/png")
      for (key, value) in parameters {
           multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
      }
    }
    }, to: url, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if let value = response.result.value as AnyObject?{
                    let json = JSON(value)
                } else {

                }                    
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)

        }
    }
    )
```

Comment: the problem is that I can't append structObject

Comment: And what is "structObject" here? I can't see where is declared

Comment: it's a simple struct

Comment: I dont get why you wanna use a struct instead of the alamofire "parameters". Maybe you can create a loop to pass the data from the struct to the parameters map.

Comment: because I send a lot of data to server: many products details, user info, ... so I use structs

Comment: Then you should make a helper function that generates a [String: String] with that data. But you cannot send a struct, you can only send the classic Alamofire "parameter". So, my answer to this is to create a helper function that returns a [String:String], and append that map to the "parameters" map. 
Make that function to receive the product detail, user info and all that stuff you need, but be sure to return a [String:String], append it to "parameters" and you should be good to go.